# MySQL query where item in column a selects item in b, and vice versa

Tags: mysql

I have two columns of data

```
Refer > Target
1 > 4
1 > 7
2 > 5
3 > 6
4 > 1
```

I want to run a query in MySQL that selects every refer that is also selected by its target. So, 1 > 4 and 4 > 1.

The furtherest I can get is:

```
SELECT refer FROM table WHERE refer IN
(SELECT target FROM table)
```

But that just lists what is in the other column, not what's matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2
  ON t1.Refer = t2.Target
  AND t1.Target = t2.Refer
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a need to over complicate this query

```
SELECT refer FROM TABLE WHERE (refer = '1' and target = '4') or (refer ='4' and target = '1')
```

Comment: When I need to select the current president of Russia, I always write a simple query: `SELECT * FROM presidents WHERE lastname = 'Putin'`

Comment: Oh wait, there's an even simpler way! `SELECT '1', '4' UNION SELECT '4', '1'` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join for this:

```
SELECT a.refer, a.target FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT refer, target FROM tbl
) b

ON a.target = b.refer AND a.refer = b.target
```